# ListViews inside ScrollView Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have on one page three vertical ListViews that are in the ScrollView. I need that these ListView to extend the ScrollView so that it can be scrolled and the ListView is not.

Below the problem in the fifth column, should scroll the page and not the column
[image]

My ScheduleWeekView Xaml code:

```
<ContentView.Content>

        <ScrollView BindingContext="{x:Reference This}" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid x:Name="ColumnGrid" ColumnSpacing="1">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <week:ColumnView
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    DayOfWeek="Mon"
                    Items="{Binding WeekObjects[0]}" />
                <week:ColumnView
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    DayOfWeek="Tue"
                    Items="{Binding WeekObjects[1]}" />
                <week:ColumnView
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    DayOfWeek="Wed"
                    Items="{Binding WeekObjects[2]}" />
                <week:ColumnView
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    DayOfWeek="Thu"
                    Items="{Binding WeekObjects[3]}" />
                <week:ColumnView
                    Grid.Column="4"
                    DayOfWeek="Fri"
                    Items="{Binding WeekObjects[4]}" />
                <week:ColumnView
                    Grid.Column="5"
                    DayOfWeek="Sat"
                    Items="{Binding WeekObjects[5]}" />
                <week:ColumnView
                    Grid.Column="6"
                    DayOfWeek="Sun"
                    Items="{Binding WeekObjects[6]}" />

                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <PinchGestureRecognizer PinchUpdated="PinchToZoomContainer_OnPinchUpdated" />
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentView.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested ListViews/ScrollViews are not supported.